# Creating new colors in xcolor for use in listings

Tags: listings, color

I'm trying to include some code using `\usepackage{listings}`. However the default look is not very pretty, so I want to customize it a bit. I've read some of the other posts about changing the layout of the code so I tried this:

```
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
    \lstset{%
    language=C++,%
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!20},% sets backgroundcolor
    basicstyle=%
    \scriptsize \color{black},% basic font setting
    commentstyle=%
    \color{OliveGreen}
    }
```

But OliveGreen is undefined. Green is not good looking at all, so I would like to know how I can mix/create my own colors? Or maybe use another package with more standard colors in it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `OliveGreen` color is defined in `dvipsnam.def`, so you get it with

```
\usepackage[rgb,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
```

Alternatively, you can define it by stating

```
\definecolor{OliveGreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
```

in your document preamble. In both cases, you can use the color by name where you wish.

With the `dvipsnames` option the `OliveGreen` color is defined in the CMYK model with what would be

```
\definecolor{OliveGreen}{cmyk}{0.64,0,0.95,0.40}
```

but the same `xcolor` package will convert it to the `rgb` specification above.

This is what I get from the following test document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rgb,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{OliveGreenCMYK}{cmyk}{0.64,0,0.95,0.40}
\definecolor{OliveGreenRGB}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}

\begin{document}

\colorbox{OliveGreenCMYK}{\rule{0pt}{1cm}\hspace{1cm}}\quad
\colorbox{OliveGreenRGB}{\rule{0pt}{1cm}\hspace{1cm}}\quad
\colorbox{OliveGreen}{\rule{0pt}{1cm}\hspace{1cm}}

\end{document}
```

which shows that the three ways of calling the color give the same result. However this can be different in the final printout, depending on the printer and the printer driver.

[image]