# Why pgfornament is not working here?

Tags: pgfornament, ornamental-fonts

I use overleaf to write latex documents. I want to add ornaments to my latex documents. So, I was reading this article,

https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/pgfornament/doc/ornaments.pdf

But the problem is none of them is working. I only used commands written up to page 9. I think there are some other things needed to bring these ornaments into the light. I haven't uploaded it in overleaf . What should I do to make use of these ornaments?

Comment: Does the provided answer solve your problem? If yes, then consider accepting the provided answer. If no, then please provide feedback regarding the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` in order to get the example to compile without errors, see [Creating new colors in xcolor for use in listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78643). The problem seems to be the color `OliveGreen` that is otherwise not known to LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfornament}

\begin{document}
\pgfornament[width = 2cm, color = red]{1}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{pgfornamentstyle/.style = {fill = SpringGreen, fill opacity = 0.5, line width = 1pt}}%
\pgfornament[color = OliveGreen, scale=1.25, anchor=south]{24}%
% Alternatively
% \pgfornament[color = blue, scale=1.25, anchor=south]{24}%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*PS: By the way, next time please provide some code together with a question, see [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/.)*